# a2billing sip invite wrong format?

Tags: asterisk, sip, voip

I am trying to implement a2billing for prepaid cards solution , I have tried to make the destination call everything is good , reading the cards and balance , but when I am asked to enter the number I wish to call , the format of sip invite get messed up ,

Example , when I try to call a number XXXX and assuming that my provider ip yy.yy.yy.yy ,phone that I call from zzzzzz, the invite would look like this :

```
INVITE sip:XXXX%7C60%7CHRrL(8508000%3A61000%3A30000)@yy.yy.yy.yy SIP/2.0
        From: <sip:zzzzzz@10.64.4.79>;tag=as07522260
        To: <sip:XXXX%7C60%7CHRrL(8508000%3A61000%3A30000)@yy.yy.yy.yy>
        Contact: <sip:zzzzzz@10.64.4.79:5060>
        Call-ID: 3ea2b73a7d68626070d3a45c4e632749@10.64.4.79:5060
        CSeq: 102 INVITE
        User-Agent: FPBX-2.11.0(11.20.0)
        Date: Thu, 05 Oct 2017 04:28:06 GMT
        Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH, MESSAGE
        Supported: replaces, timer
        Content-Type: application/sdp
        Content-Length: 277
```

the problem here is the %7C60%7CHR stuff that is added , can't seem to find the configuration to override them ,

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into most the problems that you may encounter while using asterisk and a2billing was solved by changing the global system variables,

and for my problem changing the parameter dialcommand_param

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have know, that a2billing is WEB and control part and not deal at all with invites.

Invites is sip part, it is asterisk

In your case however it is more then likly that you have incorrect trunk setup, consult with your provider or linux admin.

Comment: I solved my problem , there was a global variable , dialcommand_param
removed this and everything is ok now 
|60|HRrL(%timeout%:61000:30000)